# Trouble specifying compiler path in C/C++ extensions in vscode

Tags: c, sdk, cross-compiling, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I am coding a c app on a distant server (Using VScode Remote).
I want to specify my sdk compilator to the c/c++ vscode extension in order to make Intellisens working properly.

I have tried to specify the compilator path in the settings.json like this :

```
{
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "/opt/toolchains/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf_sdk-builroot/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc",
    "C_Cpp.loggingLevel": "Debug"
}
```

But in the debug output, it says that it hasn't found the compilator :

```
Attempting to get defaults from C++ compiler in "compilerPath" property: '/opt/toolchains/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf_sdk-builroot/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc'
Specified compiler was not found: /opt/toolchains/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf_sdk-builroot/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```

I was expecting it was dealing with rights on the sdk folder but even with `chmod 777` it doesn't work.